# Jackson: Storing type information along with the Serialized data

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I'm creating a caching library which supports different Serialization types, one of them being Jackson

Serialization is straightforward

```
public byte[] serialize(Object data) {
    return objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(data);
}
```

However, during Deserialization, deserializing it into a generic Object doesn't always work (I'm deserializing it into a generic Object as I don't have the type information available)

```
public Object deserialize(byte[] serializedData) {
    return objectMapper.readValue(decompressionInputStream, Object.class);
}
```

Is there any possible way Jackson can store the type information along with the Serialized bytes and use the same information for Deserialization?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if JSON has this feature, but you can easily add such a feature in your project. Create an abstract class that will have a method getClassName() or something
with an implementation like this

```
public String getClassName() {
 return getClass().getCanonicalName();
}
```

Then have all your classes extend this class. Better yet if you use java 8 or above, you can have this as an interface with default method implementation. Then you only will have your classes implement this interface. So when your class will get serialized it will store this property as well.